# Running into "uninitialized constant" with whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

Trying to use `whenever` gem today. Running into this error `uninitialized constant EntriesController::RedditScrapper` ... how do I fix this?

**Current Controller**

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController


def index
  @entries = Entry.all
end

def scrape

    RedditScrapper.scrape

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

**lib/reddit_scrapper.rb**

```
require 'open-uri'

module RedditScrapper
  def self.scrape
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entriesArray = []
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      entriesArray << Entry.new({ title: title, link: link })
    end

    if entriesArray.map(&:valid?)
      entriesArray.map(&:save!)
    end
  end
end
```

**config/schedule.rb**

```
RAILS_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/')

every 2.minutes do 
  runner "RedditScrapper.scrape", :environment => "development"
end
```

Please help me to figure out the right runner task to write in ...

**Application.rb**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module ScrapeModel
  class Application < Rails::Application
   config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
  end
end
```

Comment: Use @spickermann solution and use `RedditScrapper.scrape` in schedule.rb instead of calling controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails doesn't auto load the `lib` folder. You need to add the following line to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Comment: is the `config/application.rb` above correct? also, I updated the other files ...

Comment: @spikermann, well, this seems to be working as I'm no longer receiving that error ... so yay. Have other issues instead but will create a separate question post for it ... thank you.

Comment: Yes, your `application.rb` looks fine.

Comment: btw, how did you know that Rails doesn't autoload the `lib` folder?

Comment: Because this is a common issue that Rails changed its behavior of auto loading the `lib` folder. It did until Rails 3.2 and doesn't since Rails 4.0

Comment: I see. Is this something expected from a jr. developer to know?

Comment: Nope this auto loading behavior detail and especially how it changed over time is nothing I would junior expect to know. But it might be helpful to learn in general how Ruby finds and loads classes, why you need `require` in Ruby and how it works and why this is not needed in for files in Rails' `app` folder.

Comment: ok, thank you. trying to push myself to learn more, and add at least three projects on github starting from basic, to moderate, and then advanced all by end of March ... so I can start applying for junior jobs ...

Comment: thank you! Is that realistic enough to get hired for a junior job? everyone I talk to usually says to have a portfolio on github.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 there is no need to have a portfolio on github. It can be a plus but not the norm.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou, hm, well, how do I get hired for ROR jr job then? Github is the only way for me to "prove" that I can do ROR stuff ...

Comment: I would say a portfolio helps to get an invitation to an interview. Once you are in an interview the portfolio is not important anymore and it only depends on your knowledge.

Comment: @spickermann, that makes sense, ie, it gets my foot in the door but not a "guarantee" ... the problem is that there are so few junior jobs, and competition is so fierce ... I've seen job ads that expect 2 years of experience in ROR .. it's rare to find something not so ... I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you've defined `RedditScrapper` as a module, but you are trying to use it as a class... (ie calling a method on it).

You can either: turn it into a class (just change `module` to `class`) OR define all relevant methods as `module_function`s

The former is probably preferable given your chosen usage.

Comment: how do I do that? Earlier it was `runner "RedditScrapper.scrape"` .. but ran into problems with that ... so changed it to `runner "EntriesController.new.scrape", :environment => "development"` ...

Comment: ie, do I call it like this? `Module.RedditScrapper.scrape`?